# FFMPEG Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16be with MP4

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am desperately trying to cut an MP4 video with ffmpeg, following this [example] https://github.com/facebookresearch/VideoPose3D/blob/master/INFERENCE.md

```
ffmpeg -i P1060513copy.mp4 -ss 3:12 -to 3:30 -c copy output.mp4
```

I am getting this error

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P1060513.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
  Duration: 00:03:52.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 51908 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50365 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 360k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
      timecode        : 01:39:08:00
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
      timecode        : 01:39:08:00
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
      timecode        : 01:39:08:00
[mp4 @ 0x18bc2c0] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x18bc2c0] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x18bc2c0] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16be in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 50365 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 360k tbn, 360k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
      timecode        : 01:39:08:00
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-11-15 10:10:14
      timecode        : 01:39:08:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

To avoid this error I converted the file in mkv and cut it (works perfectly) and then I wanted to convert it back to MP4 but ended with the same error.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Save to `mov` or change `-c copy` to `-c:v copy`

Answer (score 9):

It seems like this is known behavior and intended by the ffmpeg developers. 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3818

Apparently the MP4 norm does not include the pcm_s16be codec and hence ffmpeg refuses to create such a file.

It's very inconvenient unfortunately. When I cut while only copying the video code, e.g.

> ffmpeg -i uncut.MP4 -ss 00:00:10.440 -to 00:00:28.440 -vcodec copy cut.MP4

I get a noticeable offset in the audio stream.

Comment: Copying just the video stream works for me without any noticeable offset in the video, e.g., using `ffmpeg -i uncut.mp4 -ss 00:02:27 -to 00:02:36 c:v copy cut.mp4` seems to work fine, re-encoding the audio to AAC without any offset.  This is in the current `ffmpeg 4.3.1.` Thanks for your posted answer, it helped me get past the issue quickly.

Comment: @Basil's answer worked, altho on his comment it seems like he missed a hyphen, should've been `-c:v copy`, so: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:01:23 -to 00:03:21 -c:v copy output.mp4`

Comment: @Seraf you're right, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 5):

Save to `mov` or change `-c copy` to `-c:v copy`

```bash
# Changing to -c:v copy
$ ffmpeg -i P1060513copy.mp4 -ss 3:12 -to 3:30 -c:v copy output.mp4

# Changing to .mov
$ ffmpeg -i P1060513copy.mp4 -ss 3:12 -to 3:30 -c copy output.mov
```

Comment: mov thing worked thanks.

Comment: -c:v copy worked thanks.

Comment: I was expecting this to lose audio because of the missing `-c:a copy`, but... it doesn't?

Comment: That's true @BallpointBen , it will re-encode the audio portion.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is that ffmpeg is following strict mp4 compliance and will not process (though it has the ability to process both the video and the audio codecs).

What I did in this scenario is to pre-process the files by filtering out all the mp4s that use pcm_s16be (standard in Sony alpha cameras) and encoding only the audio into aac and leaving video stream un-encoded (to preserve the quality)

TLDR: (Do both these steps)

```
ffmpeg -i P1060513copy.mp4 -acodec aac -vcodec copy temp_P1060513copy.mp4

ffmpeg -i temp_P1060513copy.mp4 -ss 3:12 -to 3:30 -c copy P1060513copy_cut.mp4
```

My requirement was slightly different because I needed to rotate my videos using ffmpeg, but ffmpeg would not allow me since the input has PCM (because some Sony cameras have that).  So before the rotation, I first needed to convert PCM to AAC. (Reason I choose AAC instead of flac is because many softwares dont allow smooth edits with flac - eg. DaVinci)

Following is my code to achieve the above:

**1 - To identify the audio codec** (before using ffmpeg, am using ffprobe to gather all the metadata and help me filter)

```
ffprobe_command = "ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1  "
status, audio_codec = subprocess.getstatusoutput(ffprobe_command+ " " + "\"" + one_file + "\" ")
```

**2 - To encode only those files identified above**

```
if audio_codec == 'pcm_s16be':
    print("pcm_s16be found, hence processing further")
    status, converted_result = subprocess.getstatusoutput("ffmpeg -i " + "\"" + str(one_file) + "\"" +" -acodec aac -vcodec copy " + "\"" + "pcm_"  + one_file + "\"")
```

Note: Am running this as part of a larger python program, and this runs inside a loop, hence the references to 'one_file' etc.

If the above python snippet is confusing you, you can use this for individual files.

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -acodec aac -vcodec copy output_file.mp4
```

After both these steps the mp4 will now have aac as audio codec and ffmpeg will allow this for any downstream encodes.

You can check the section under **Stream Mapping** to confirm that only the audio is re-encoded.

> pcm_s16be found, hence processing further
>
> ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
> configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
> libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
> libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
> libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
> libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
> libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
> libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
> libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
> libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000022621729280] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 1000
> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000022621729280] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 1000.
> Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : XAVC
> minor_version   : 16785407
> compatible_brands: XAVCmp42iso2
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> Duration: 00:00:14.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 95986 kb/s
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 94241 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> handler_name    : Video Media Handler
> encoder         : AVC Coding
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
> Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (rtmd / 0x646D7472), 204 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> handler_name    : Timed Metadata Media Handler
> timecode        : 00:03:24:12
>
> Stream mapping:
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
> Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be (native) -> aac (native))
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
> Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : XAVC
> minor_version   : 16785407
> compatible_brands: XAVCmp42iso2
> encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
> Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-4), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 94241 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 25k tbc (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> handler_name    : Video Media Handler
> encoder         : AVC Coding
> Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2018-12-15T00:56:11.000000Z
> handler_name    : Sound Media Handler
> encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
> frame=   78 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   32256kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate=86920.4kbits/s speed=5.99x
> frame=  140 fps=130 q=-1.0 size=   57856kB time=00:00:05.52 bitrate=85861.1kbits/s speed=5.14x
> frame=  218 fps=139 q=-1.0 size=   94208kB time=00:00:08.64 bitrate=89322.8kbits/s speed=5.49x
> frame=  288 fps=139 q=-1.0 size=  124160kB time=00:00:11.44 bitrate=88908.7kbits/s speed= 5.5x
> frame=  357 fps=138 q=-1.0 size=  160256kB time=00:00:14.20 bitrate=92451.7kbits/s speed= 5.5x
> frame=  360 fps=137 q=-1.0 Lsize=  165896kB time=00:00:14.40 bitrate=94376.2kbits/s speed=5.48x
> video:165658kB audio:226kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.006983%
> [aac @ 000002262173a940] Qavg: 176.176